# Simultaneous equations involving $\sqrt2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm enjoying a sabbatical and using the time to revisit mathematics for the first time in many years. I'm working through the Cambridge University Pure Mathematics books. The text and questions seem very good. The last question at the end of each section always seems to be just beyond my reach. I've puzzled at this one for a whole day and slept on it, but I'm still stumped. Hoping I can get some help here...

Solve the simultaneous equations: 
\begin{align}
5x-3y &= 41 \\ 
(7\sqrt2)x + (4\sqrt2)y &= 82.
\end{align}

Thank You

Gary

Comment: You can divide through the second equation by $\sqrt 2$ (or multiply by $\sqrt 2$ and then cancel the factor of $2$ which appears) which makes the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ both integers.

Comment: Add $4\sqrt 2$ times the first equation to $3$ times the second.

Comment: $\sqrt 2$ is just like other numbers are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the first equation we get
$$x=\frac{41}{5}+\frac{3}{5}y$$ thus
$$7\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{41}{5}+\frac{3}{5}y\right)+4\sqrt{2}y=82$$
solve this for $y$

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes I just need pointing in the right direction. $y = 5\sqrt2 - 7$ and $x = 3\sqrt2 + 4$

Answer (score 1):

For the set of equations
\begin{align}
5x-3y &= 41 \\ 
(7\sqrt2)x + (4\sqrt2)y &= 82,
\end{align}
it can be seen that
\begin{align}
5 x - 3 y &= 41 \\ 
7 x + 4 y &= 41 \sqrt{2}.
\end{align}
Multiply the first by $4$ and the second by $3$ to obtain
\begin{align}
20 x - 12 y &= 4 \cdot 41 \\ 
21 x + 12 y &= 3 \cdot 41 \sqrt{2}.
\end{align}
Add the equation and get $41 x = 41 \, (4 + 3 \sqrt{2})$ or $x = 4 + 3 \sqrt{2}$. With the value of $x$ use the first equation in the form
$$y = \frac{5 x - 41}{3}$$ 
to obtain $y = -7 + 5 \sqrt{2}$.